# Binary search recursive function not working if target is either the first, or last element in the array

Tags: ruby, binary-tree

I've been working on this recursive function in Ruby for quite some time now. There's one problem, which I can't seem to fix on my own.

```
def bsearch(array, target)
    pos = (array.length - 1) / 2
    return pos if array[pos] == target
    if array[pos] < target
        pos += bsearch(array[pos..-1], target)
    else
        pos -= bsearch(array[0..pos], target)
    end
end
```

The code seems to work as long as the target isn't the first or last element in the array. I can't find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```rb
pos -= bsearch(array[0..pos], target)
```

should actually be

```rb
bsearch(array[0..pos], target)
```

If you think about it, if your array has length 200, and the item you are looking for is in position 5 of the first half of the array, it is also in position 5 of the wohle array.

Comment: This isn't working if the target is the last element of the array. Eg. bsearch([1,2,3, 4, 5, 7, 9], 9)

Comment: Your answer doesn't in cases where the target is the final element of the array. I fixed that by adding "return 1 if array[-1] == target && array.length <= 2"

Comment: @Roarke you can alternatively use `pos = array.length / 2` instead of `pos = (array.length - 1) / 2`, which gives you the right cut point.